# How to create Master Detail view with two user controls in MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, prism

I am little confused about how to create Master Detail view with two different user controls.

There are three choices,

**Choice 1**

```
CustomerMasterView + CustomerMasterViewModel
CustomerDetailView + CustomerDetailViewModel
```

And keep both View Models in App.Resources

But by doing this, binding becomes complex with all static resources source markup code.

**Choice 2**

```
CustomerViewModel
CustomerMasterView
CustomerDetailView
```

Both views share same ViewModel via App.Resources, well even with the binding code has too many items.

**Choice 3**

```
CustomerMasterView + CustomerMasterViewModel
CustomerDetailView + CustomerDetailViewModel
```

Both view's have DataContext set to their corresponding ViewModel. Now here is the little issue, 
  CustomerMasterView has Selector (ListBox or DataGrid or whatever), whose SelectedItem needs to be bound to CustomerDetailViewModel's "Customer" Property as two way binding.

Does it look good?

```
<!-- CustomerMasterView -->

<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.Customer,ElementName=customerDetailView}"
    />

<local:CustomerDetailView
    x:Name="customerDetailView"
    />
```

But by doing this, I am defying purpose of ViewModel as it adds more dependency in my UI code.

Which one is most preferred way or is there any other way?
Should I create nested View Models?

I am also trying to learn Prism, and I have little confusion of how to do this right, any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest appraoch in my opinion would be to have a single view model, with two UserControls.

Your ViewModel would have your list of customers, as well as a "ActiveCustomer" or "SelectedCustomer".  Your MasterView (with the DataContext set to you ViewModel), would contain your list, wired up like this:

`<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Your MasterView will also include your DetailsView (another UserControl).  It looks like this:

`<views:DetailsUserControl DataContext="{Binding ActiveItem}" />`

Comment: Instead I am using nested view model for ActiveItem because detail view model has already many things.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to implement a Master/Detail scenario with two Views (separate UserControls) and two ViewModels.